# UPDATE and FROM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I saw this query in one of the posts, to update a table by the records on another table, but I couldn't understand logic behind it. Especially I have never used FROM in an UPDATE query.

***And...***

*(If I want to be blunt, I should say I am looking for an insight to understand how can I translate/debug/trace or in a nutshell understand SQL results by each line. When I see a line of code I know what is it doing, but so far, I could only memorize structure of SQL queries by practice.
I want to know which line would be processed first, what comes next and... so I can write more complex codes. Could you please provide me with a reference?)*

```
UPDATE
    T
SET
    T.col1 = OT.col1,
    T.col2 = OT.col2
FROM
    Some_Table T
INNER JOIN
    Other_Table OT
ON
    T.id = OT.id
WHERE
    T.col3 = 'cool'
```

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: SQL is not prcoedural. It doesn't do things line by line. If you are using SQL Server (please enlighten us and add a tag), press CTRL-L to see what it's doing behind the scenes. For example the first thing it might do is try and find all the `Some_Table` records that = 'cool'. Or the first thing it might do is find all the keys that might match. and it may or may not do this in parallel.

Comment: Concerning your second question (execution order), if you're dealing with SQL Server, you might be interested in [the 2009 diagram by Itzik Ben-Gan, "Logical Query Processing"](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf). It documents the logical execution order of the various clauses of a `SELECT` query. Not sure if there is a similar poster somewhere for `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014 for now, and the diagram is very interesting!! I am looking for something like that to understand how queries are processed. I am very disappointed about references on SQL Queries. I know the syntax could be different somehow, and the abilities. I am really confused with logic behind processing queries in DBMS's.

Comment: You have to understand it is _set based_ not procedural. Take a look at the query plan as I suggested as this may help to understand.

Comment: Yeah, I have done that Nick. It's good to understand what a whole query do at the end, but I'm looking for an insight to write queries, whatever I need. Therefore, I guess I need to know output of each level, and to know which section gives from which section! Check this, it's an interesting chart:
https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/chap1_9780735658363/elementLinks/httpatomoreillycomsourcemspimages1137358.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I found that in SQL Engines, hierarchies of processing commands are different, so there is no unique way of thinking and understanding SQL like lines of codes.
I also found out that FROM is usually process at first, and then it will goes up to select. In all SQL commands there are a unique hierarchy, so I simply think about SQL a human language and then try to find the logical way to do what I think it should have done, and in most cases this will work.

For example, in SELECT, the machine should first bring a table, and then find what condition should be apply, so WHERE is next, and then the data should be prepared for viewing, so SELECT will be processed next. This is the closest thing I found. :)

Answer (score 1):

Frist of all try this:

```
SELECT    
T.col1 , OT.col1,
T.col2 , OT.col2
FROM
    Some_Table T
INNER JOIN
    Other_Table OT
ON
    T.id = OT.id
WHERE
    T.col3 = 'cool'
```

This will show you what is the result of the update would be.

Comment: Thanks. :) Doing a select could be very helpful in UPDATE queries. I understand what is it doing, but I'm looking to understand logic behind SQL Queries.